# deleting an element in a struct by using delete operator

Tags: c++

I have a struct like this:

```
struct m_doc{
char id[30];
int ISBN[30];
char title[50];
char author[50];
int year[30];
```

};

As I'm trying to delete an element inside it by using the delete operator, this happened:

```
if (doc.id[i] == doc.id[j])
    delete[] doc.author[j], doc.id[j], doc.ISBN[j], doc.title[j], doc.year[j];//expression must have pointer type
```

The error is on the doc of doc.author only, while the others are fine.

Comment: None of those things should be deleted.

Comment: what do you expect to happen after deleting a structure member not initialized with new?

Comment: Only `delete` what you got from `new`. Similarly, only `delete[]` what you got from `new[]`.

Comment: Also you can't delete several pointers by one delete / delete[] statement. `delete[] a, b, c;` actually deletes the result of the comma operator, which would be `a`.

Comment: @Kirinyale Actually, `a, b, c` evaluates to `c` (the last one.)  Your example will be parsed as `(delete[] a), b, c` due to operator precedence of C++ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence and that's why he got an error only at `doc.author[j]`; the rest merely evaluates to scalar values such as `doc.year[j]`.

Comment: @nodakai Yes, my mistake. I've already realized that, but you were faster.

Comment: Perhaps we should make that `delete p,q;` form illegal in C++17. I strongly suspect that all current uses of that are unintended leaks of `q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array declared that way are deleted automatically when they go out of scope.
You only have to delete arrays declared like this:

```
int* array = new int[30];
//Do work
delete[] array;
```

You should however prefer `std::vector` over the latter array style and `std::array` instead of the arrays you used in your code. It is much less error prone.

In your case (and almost always), `std::vector` is the most appropriate data type. Then you can do stuff like this:

```
if (doc.id[i] == doc.id[j]) {
    doc.author.erase(doc.author.begin() + j);
    //and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may only delete what you have created with new.  You could create a pointer as follows:
m_doc *instance = new m_doc();

Then you could delete that later...

delete m_doc;

Or you could create each of the members as pointers which are manually newed up.